# Smart pointer to lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, shared-ptr

I'm trying to make a function that accepts a shared pointer to some functor. With manually crafted functors there're no problems, but with lambda there are. I know that I can't use `decltype` with lambda - every new lambda declaration creates a new type. Right now I'm writing:

```
auto lambda = [](int a, float b)->int
{
    return 42;
};
using LambdaType = decltype(lambda);

shared_ptr<LambdaType> ptr{ new LambdaType{ lambda } };
```

It works, but looks ugly. Moreover there's a copy constructor call! Is there any way to simplify?

Comment: You are trying to use lambdas together with smart pointers in a way that doesn't really make sense, this would be so much easier if you used `std::function` instead. You *do* use the smart pointer right IMO, as a resource-wrapper instead of just a simple self-deleting pointer. As for the "extra indirection" by `std::function`, is that really going to be a bottleneck in your code? It's no more of extra redirection than using smart pointers really, and using `std::function` you have a nicer and much cleaner syntax, both when setting up and when using/calling the function.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/997216714e0e7d74

Comment: Oh, and using `std::function` doesn't limit you to use only lambdas, what if the people maintaining your code, or otherwise using your code, would like to use a non-lambda function? With your own "smart function pointer" types that's not possible. Furthermore, since each lambda have a unique type, the shared pointer can only be used for the specific lambda and no other lambdas with the same signature.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I agree with you. But it's a matter of usability - I don't want the user limit only to `std::function`. Btw, I have an overload for `std::function` and functors. Now I want to add the same for lambdas.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I also thought about this. But again - unnecessary move/copy constructors.

Comment: I'm just curious, but why "reimplement the wheel"? Why create functionality that already exists in the standard library? And the issue with lambda-type is not really something you can work past. All lambdas have a unique type, it doesn't depend on the signature.

Comment: And before you start thinking about "unnecessary" operations, ***measure***, ***benchmark***. Premature optimization is the root of all evil and all that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Again I agree with you. But I'm comparing with any other object where I can call `make_shared` and create smart pointer in place. I can't do this with lambda, or at least I don't know how. Regarding the usage - sure, I can change the design to only accept `std::function`, if I'll find that lambda-approach is ugly, but for now I want to iterate and see how things will go.

Comment: In that case continue experimenting, that's a very good way to learn. :) But I *do* think you're overcomplicating things though. :)

Comment: Where, exactly, are you using that ugly code?  If client code is providing a lambda, I will have the type of the lambda in my function signature.

Comment: @Yakk The client should provide me a shared pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambdas are merely auto written invokable objects to make simple code simple.  It you want something beyond their default automatic storage behavior, write the type they write yourself.

It is illegal to have a lambda type in an unevaluated context.  In an evaluated context, it creates a lambda in automatic storage.  You want it on the free store.  This requires at least logically a copy.

A horrible hack involving violating the unevaluated context rule, sizeof/alignof, aligned_storage_t, placement new, possibly unbounded compile time recursion (or maybe one with a `static_assert`), returning pointers to local variables, and the aliasing constructor of shared ptr, and requiring callers to write insane code might avoid calling the copy/move.  But it is a bad idea, and simply using invokable objects is easier.

Of course, accepting the copy/move makes it trivial.  But at that point, just use `std::function` unless you need something like varargs.

You state you do not want to force users to use `std::function`; but `std::function` would implicitly convert a compatible lambda into itself.

If you are willing to accept a copy, we can do this:

```
template<class T>
std::shared_ptr<std::decay_t<T>>
auto_shared( T&& t ) {
  return std::make_shared<std::decay_t<T>>(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

then `auto ptr = auto_shared( [x=0]()mutable{ return x++; } );` is a non-type-erased shared pointer to a counting lambda.  The lambda is copied (well, moved) into the shared storage.

If you want to avoid that copy, the client can write a manual function object and call `make_shared<X>(ctor_args)` on it.

There is no reasonable way to separate a lambdas type from its construction in C++ at this point.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) as type.

Comment: Yes, I know. As I wrote there're no problems with "usual" functors. But lambda is a bit different. And `std::function` creates one more level of indirection.

Comment: Well, you need indirection for type erasure and you need type erasure to hide the ad-hoc type of a lambda. So, you're not going to do much better than `std::function`, which works identically for both lambdas and functors.

Answer (score 1):

if you catch something in lambda, it becomes algorithmically same as `std::function`, so use it freely. Also, `std::function` implements captured values memory management, so using `std::shared_ptr` on top of it is not required.

If you catch nothing, lambda is convertible to simple function pointer:

```
int(*ptr)(int,int) = [](int a, int b) -> int {
    return a+b;
};
```

Functions are allocated statically and definitely shouldn't be deleted. So, you don't actually need `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: It's not convertible if it have a capture.